# Gitlab: Fail job in "after_script"?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, pipeline

Consider this .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
variables:
  var1: "bob"
  var2: "bib"

job1:
  script:
    - "[[ ${var1} == ${var2} ]]"

job2:
  script:
    - echo "hello"
  after_script:
    - "[[ ${var1} == ${var2} ]]"
```

In this example, job1 fails as expected but job2 succeeds, incomprehensibly. Can I force a job to fail in the `after_script` section?

Note: `exit 1` has the same effect as `"[[ ${var1} == ${var2} ]]"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The status of a job is determined solely by its `script:`/`before_script:` sections (the two are simply concatenated together to form the job script).

`after_script:` is a completely different construct -- it is not part of the job script. It is mainly for taking actions after a job is completed. `after_script:` runs even when jobs fail beforehand, for example.

Per [the docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#after_script): (emphasis added on the last bullet)

> Scripts you specify in `after_script` execute in a new shell, separate from any `before_script` or `script` commands. As a result, they:
>
> - Have the current working directory set back to the default (according to the variables which define how the runner processes Git requests).
> - Don’t have access to changes done by commands defined in the `before_script` or `script`, including:
>
>   - Command aliases and variables exported in `script` scripts.
>   - Changes outside of the working tree (depending on the runner executor), like software installed by a `before_script` or `script` script.
> - Have a separate timeout, which is hard-coded to 5 minutes.
> - **Don’t affect the job’s exit code. If the `script` section succeeds and the `after_script` times out or fails, the job exits with code `0` (`Job Succeeded`).**